# Numpad key events result in stuck keys from GetKeyboardState

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, keyboard-events

I've got a C++ (MFC) app that needs to check the keystate on a timer. If the user is holding down a key, we delay processing of some code.

Here's the check for the `keydown`:

```
if (!GetKeyboardState(keyState)) 
{
    s_executeDeferredResult = e_executeDeferredButtonCheckFailed;
    return;
}   
s_executeDeferredStuckKeys.clear();
for (int index=0; index<arrsize(keyState); ++index)
{
    if (keyState[index] & 0x80)
    {
        s_executeDeferredStuckKeys.insert(index);
    }
}
if (!s_executeDeferredStuckKeys.empty())
{
    s_executeDeferredResult = e_executeDeferredButtonsActive;
    return;
}
```

But, there are some key combos that get stuck:

1. Turn on <kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>NumPad8</kbd>
4. Release <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>
5. Release <kbd>NumPad8</kbd>
   (this is one example, there are others, including a doozy with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd>)

`GetKeyboardState` will now report that `VK_UP` is pressed.

The events that happen are (corresponding to the actions above).

1. `<None>`
2. `WM_KEYDOWN`, `VK_SHIFT`
3. `WM_KEYUP`, `VK_SHIFT`
   `WM_KEYDOWN`, `VK_UP`
   `WM_KEYDOWN`, `VK_SHIFT`
4. `WM_KEYUP`, `VK_SHIFT`
5. `WM_KEYUP`, `VK_NUMPAD8`

So, Windows doesn't recognize that the Up key came up, and now `GetKeyboardState` is broken.

Is there any good way to check the real state of the key? `GetAsyncKeyState` and `GetKeyState` both report that the key is down as well.

Comment: Have you tried with another keyboard?

Comment: Yes, it happens on all the keyboards we've tried.

Comment: Since this is an MFC application make sure to check your `PreTranslateMessage` implementation. That's where all sorts of bad accumulate over time. Also note the remark on the [`GetKeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299.aspx) documentation: *"The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue."* In other words: If your application does something fishy, chances are that `GetKeyboardState` gets confused.

Comment: This behavior is reproducible in a small self-contained test app, as it turns out. Good thought though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

I hooked into the keyboard events in InitInstance and am tracking the ups and downs by scan code (a map with the scan code as key and the virtual keys as the value).

```
m_keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, &KeyboardHook, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
```

---

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHook(
    __in int nCode,
    __in WPARAM wParam,
    __in LPARAM lParam
    )
{
    // According to the docs, we're not allowed to do any "further processing" if nCode is < 0.
    // According to the docs, we should process messages if we get code HC_ACTION. 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984(v=vs.85).aspx
    // It doesn't specify what to do if another code comes in, so we will just ignore any other codes.
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        uint8 scanCode = (uint8)((lParam & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        uint8 virtKey = (uint8)wParam;
        if (lParam & 0x80000000) // key up
            KeyState::SetKeyUp(scanCode);
        else
            KeyState::SetKeyDown(scanCode, virtKey);
    }

    // We must call the next hook in the chain, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    // First param is ignored, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

So, my defer checking becomes:

```
// Similarly, don't process deferred events if there are keys or mouse buttons which are currently down.
s_executeDeferredStuckKeys.clear();
if (KeyState::AnyKeysDown(s_excludeKeys, arrsize(s_excludeKeys)))
{
    s_executeDeferredResult = e_executeDeferredButtonsActive;
    KeyState::GetDownKeys(s_executeDeferredStuckKeys);
    return;
}
```